# Dynamically generate the content of Drop Down list via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, drop-down-menu

I am new to Javascript, JSON and jQuery. So please be easy on me. I have a JSP page that contain a drop down list. The contents of the drop down list are populated when the page is loaded. I wrote a Servlet that return the contain of the drop down list in the form of Map, and convert it to JSON string and sent back to the jsp via `response.getWriter().write(json);` However I am having trouble to getting the result back from the jsp side, and populate the contain of the drop down list from the result. Here are my codes

`customer.jsp`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  getCustomerOption('customer'); //try to pre-populate the customer drop down list
});

function getCustomerOption(ddId) {
  var dd = $('#' + ddId);
  $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/WebApps/DDListJASON", function(opts) {
      $('>option', dd).remove(); // Remove all the previous option of the drop down
      if (opts) {
        $.each(opts, function(key, value) {
            dd.append($('<option/>').val(key).text(value));
          }
        }
      });
  }
```

`down where the drop down list is generated`

```
<select id="customer" name="customer">  
    <option></option>  
</select>
```

The result is nothing get populated into the list. So sad

Comment: Just updated the codes. It is correct now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are invoking the wrong function in document ready

Shouldn't it be

```
getInitialOption('customer');
```

instead of

```
getCustomerOption('customer');
```

Answer (score 0):

You may add additional `<option>` elements to a `<select>` with the code:

```
$("#selectID").append("<option>" + text + "</option>");
```

see: [JQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand $(''), but I'm not sure that's the problem either, hard to tell exactly.

I do know it will be quicker if you do create the list of options in-memory and then do one append with .html(options) rather than append them one at a time. That may make it easier to understand also, to build the html up one line at a time and then append it.